# Factor for rows without attribute and rows with attribute and additional characteristic

Tags: regression, experiment-design, categorical-encoding

I have run an experiment in which I've measured some metric *X*, and collected an associated attribute `attr`'s value **if and only if** the value of *X* exceeds some threshold *t*. If a case's *X* value doesn't exceed *t*, then `attr` is not captured. Here's what my data look like:

```
ID  attr_val  no_attr  outcome
 0       NaN        1        0
 1       NaN        1        1
 2         0        0        1
 3         4        0        1
 4         2        0        1
 5         1        0        0
```

Where `ID` is a unique identifier for each case, `no_attr` indicates whether the `attr` value was captured for that particular case (i.e. whether the `X` value exceeded *t*), and the binary outcome `outcome` is shown.

Now, I want to predict outcome based on the attribute value if a case's *X* exceeded *t*, and I also want to measure whether a case's *X* **not exceeding *t*** is predictive, as well.

In order to keep IDs 0 and 1 in the model, `attr_val` will need to be populated with some value, not just nulls. But I don't really feel comfortable filling in 0, for example, because IDs 0 and 1 didn't have a chance to give their `attr_val` because their *X* values didn't exceed *t*. However, this *X*-exceeding-*t* criterion is very important to my experiment, so I can't just take the `attr_val`s for rows 0 and 1 anyway.

Running a logistic regression of the form `outcome ~ attr_val + no_attr` currently would make the design matrix singular, as just zeroes are included for `no_attr` if I haven't filled in any nulls in `attr_val`. **Is the right approach here to augment `no_attr` by 1 so we're not multiplying by zeroes down the line?** Or is there a better way to encode this problem?

Comment: Do you not want to use $X$ itself as part of the the predictor, since you have measured it? Or has the value of $X$ been discarded? Are the attribute values numeric or are they just arbitrary categorical labels? Does an attribute value of 4 mean that $X$ was higher than when the attribute is 1 or 2?

Comment: The value of X has been discarded. The attribute values are continuous in `[0, inf)`. To your last question, no; the inverse of the `no_attr` (`has_attr`?) is essentially a link for a particular case's being able to have a value for `attr_val`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question of this sort are easily resolved by writing down your model.

Suppose you *did* use some number, say $a$, to represent the missing values of `attr_val`.  Then your model would be in the form

$$\Pr(\text{outcome}) = h(\beta_0 + \beta_{\text{attr_val}} [\text{attr_val}] + \beta_{\text{no_attr}} [\text{no_attr}])$$

for your chosen link function $h$. Since the probabilities depend on the argument of $h$, we will focus on its values.

Consider two cases:

1. `attr_val` is not missing.  Then `no_attr` is zero and $$\Pr(\text{outcome}) = h(\beta_0 + \beta_{\text{attr_val}} [\text{attr_val}]  ).$$
2. `attr_val` is missing.  Then `attr_val` is set to the value $a$, `no_attr` equals $1$, and the formula becomes  $$\Pr(\text{outcome}) = h(\beta_0 + \beta_{\text{attr_val}} a + \beta_{\text{no_attr}} ).$$

You may interpret $(1)$ as a model for the output when `attr_val` is not missing and $(2)$ determines the fit when `attr_val` is missing.  **If you conveniently choose $a=0$,** this simplifies further: $\beta_0 + \beta_{\text{no_attr}}$ determines the fit in such cases, allowing you to interpret $\beta_{\text{no_attr}}$ as a change in the intercept $\beta_0$ attributed to the circumstances $X\le t$.